# Change php variable depending on what selected in dropdown

Tags: php, html, variables, drop-down-menu

I want to create a page on my website which will be used to view users profiles. When the user first visits the page I want it show their own profile. But I want to put in a drop-down menu or something which will give them the ability to view other users profiles. I haven't started creating this yet however I just want to know if what I want to achieve is possible with what I have planned.

What I am thinking of doing is have a php variable which would be `$UserID` or something.

To start with `$UserID` would be equal to the current user viewing the page's id e.g. 1 for Admin.

Then I would get all the data from the database through that variable `$UserID`.

But in order to view other user's profiles I want to change that `$UserID` variable depending on which user's name is selected in the dropdown.

e.g. If dropdownuser = Test3 then `$UserID` = 5.

Then it would display Test3's user profile.

Have I got this correct??

Comment: @haseeb Please don't use backticks for anything but _code_, see e.g. [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88) why. And while you're editing, please also fix other issues like i -> I

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Is that better??

Comment: #Danbyization The `$UserID` etc part in backticks was fine (you can click on "edited # min ago" and choose rollback if you want to re-apply them by the way), but @haseeb also put some around "page's id e.g. 1" and the "e.g." which are no code

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done on two separate pages: profile of the current user (my profile) and general profile page.

On my profile page you use the logged in user's ID, something like `$_SESSION['user-id']` and on general profile pages you use the ID from a drop down or whatever coming through the URL so something like `$_GET['user-id']`.

Comment: So i can't do it all on one page??

Comment: Of course you can, but I don't recommend it. For example "my profile" needs to be editable so the current user can update his profile while the he can't change the others. It's much healthier to use separate pages.

Comment: So i would have one page which would display the current user's profile and have options to edit it and one page which would open with just a dropdown for them to select the user's profile they want to visit and then when they have selected one it would open a new page which would show the user's profile that they selected??

Comment: you don't need two pages for general profiles. put the dropdown on the same page, top right corner for example...

Comment: But then how would the profile change depending on what is selected in the dropdown because PHP is run when the page loads isn't it????

Answer (score 0):

Correct. When you query the database, pass in an ID so it get's the info for that specific ID

```
$select = $db->query('SELECT id, name, info FROM table WHERE id = :id');
$select->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['id']));
```

and your html would be

```
<form method="post">
<select name="id">
<option value="1">Person 1</option>
<option value="2">Person 2</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Select user" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can achieve what you want, just note that PHP script is not active while user watches a page. It works just when the page loads (or reloads). So, you will need to reload the page when user changes the selected item in the dropdown. That is easily achievable, simply make it in `onchange` event handler.

There is another way of doing it: AJAX. You can invoke the server-side not on page load, but on some internal page event (like dropdown selected index change). Then the page would not reload, but you will need to properly handle AJAX response. For the server it would be like a new page is being loaded. Read more about [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX).

Comment: Onchange, no doubt. But it will reload the page.